# How do I get Supabase database types?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-py

I'm coming from Firebase I'm trying to get the types for database. For example, I'm used to get the type for timestamp like this:

```
import type { Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';

export type User = {
 //..   
 createdAt: Timestamp;   
 updatedAt: Timestamp | null; 
};
```

How do I get the types for Supabase database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the official Supabase docs for Generating Types. There are few examples as well that you can refer to.

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/generating-types

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import { Database } from '../types/supabase'

const supabase = createClient<Database>(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
  process.env.SUPABASE_SECRET_KEY
)

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const allOnlineUsers = await supabase.from('users').select('*').eq('status', 'ONLINE')
  res.status(200).json(allOnlineUsers)
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, but I'm unsure how to define createdAt or updatedAt as shown in the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your own types for individual tables, e.g.

```
  import supabase from '~/lib/supabase'
  import type { Database } from '~/lib/database.types'

  async function getMovies() {
    return await supabase.from('movies').select('id, title, actors(\*)')
  }

  type Actors = Database['public']['tables']['actors']['row']
  type MoviesResponse = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getMovies>>
  type MoviesResponseSuccess = MoviesResponse['data'] & {
  actors: Actors[]
  }
```

form docs https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select